# Trouble binding a rich:dataTable

Tags: java, jsf, binding, richfaces

I'm having some problems with defining a binding bean for my rich:dataTable.

The contents of the datatable are already defined in the XHTML, I just want to use the binding to read the rows back later so that the table contents can be exported into a PDF.

In my XHTML file, I put

```
<rich:dataTable ... binding="#{backingBean.tableBinding}">
```

Then, in my backing bean, I declare a member:

```
import org.richfaces.component.html.HtmlDataTable;
class BackingBean {
   private HtmlDataTable tableBinding ;
   public BackingBean() {
      tableBinding = new HtmlDataTable() ;
   }
   // ... (incl. getters and setters for binding)
 } ;
```

However, this results in:

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeBegin(UIComponentBase.java:809)

when I try to load the page. Is there something I need to do with the HtmlDataTable variable besides simply constructing it? Is it even possible to use the binding attribute in the way I intend here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't create an instance of *HtmlDataTable* yourself in the constructor. RichFaces will create an instance and inject it to your BackingBean. All you need is an public getter and setter.